# MySQL result returns nothing, no error

Tags: python, mysql

I have some issues with my Python script, it has 5 methods which call each other because they depend on the method before.

2 of them do insert, 3 of them select data from the database.
Even when i am using 5 different database connections and 5 different cursors its not pulling a result and the array returns me none, in the 4 method for example.

It fails at the 4h Method when i try to call this:

```
cursor = conn4.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT G_groups_id,id FROM adgroups WHERE G_groups_id = " + str(G_groups_id) + "" )
print("SELECT G_groups_id,id FROM adgroups WHERE G_groups_id = " + str(G_groups_id) + "")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print(data) (returns none aka empty)
```

If i try the same select with phpmyadmin it returns me a result, any ideas?

Comment: What does the `print` return?  Please edit your question.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: Possibly it is your quoting. use single quotes in your where clause